# I got a HTML & CSS progress bar. what i need now is that it should load a page on complete. any ways?

Tags: html, css, onload, progress

//Here is my HTML
What i need here is that on complete load of the progress bar it should redirect to another page.
any ways for that?!!!!

```css
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.progress {
    background-color: #e5e9eb;
    height: 0.25em;
    position: relative;
    width: 24em;
}
.progress-bar {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-name: width;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #4cd964, #5ac8fa, #007aff, #34aadc, #5856d6, #ff2d55);
    background-size: 24em 0.25em;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.progress-shadow {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eaecee, transparent);
    height: 4em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    transform: skew(45deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/* ANIMATIONS */
@keyframes width {
       0%, 100% {
       transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.65, 0.85);
  }
  0% {
       width: 0;
  }
   100% {
      width: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes width {
       0%, 100% {
       transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.65, 0.85);
  }
  0% {
       width: 0;
  }
   100% {
      width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center">Loading</h2>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <div class="progress-shadow"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

help me out!!
And i don't have any java script here.
i would be more happy if i can do it without java script.
so please help me out with it.

**UPDATE**
***found that java script animation end may help out.***

Comment: Also want to know this! 
http://jsfiddle.net/Katherina/9w7pntmt/
made a jsfiddle for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [this trick highlighted by David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback). He did it for `transitionend`, but we can swap it out for `animationend` instead.

His trick is to loop through the list of all vendor-prefixed and native `animationend` events, and check if the browser supports any of them. He then attaches the recognized `animationend` handler to the element of interest.

When the animationend event is fired, we simply redirect to the URL of interest using `window.location.replace()`, [as mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery).

I have modified it so it would work for your scenario:

```
$(function() {

    // Check with animationend event is supported by browser
    function whichAnimationEvent(){
        var t;
        var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
        var animations = {
          'animation':'animationend',
          'OAnimation':'oAnimationEnd',
          'MozAnimation':'animationend',
          'WebkitAnimation':'webkitAnimationEnd'
        }

        for(t in animations){
            if( el.style[t] !== undefined ){
                return animations[t];
            }
        }
    }

    // Listen for animation
    var animationEvent = whichAnimationEvent(),
        progress = document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar')[0];

    animationEvent && progress.addEventListener(animationEvent, function() {
        // Alert (to demonstrate the code works)
        alert('Animation complete!  This is the callback, no library needed!');

        // Redirect script
        window.location.replace('/path/to/url');
    });
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/9w7pntmt/3/

Comment: It works perfect in jsfiddle. but not on my server, Please press JS hint and see the errors.

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran What error messages do you have in your browser console? If it works in a fiddle, it should work elsewhere as long as jQuery is loaded. `window.location.replace` only works for same-origin requests. And [**closing `;` are optional in JS when there is a linebreak**](http://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript). That has nothing to do with the code working or not, only for consistency reasons.

Comment: may be the problem is that the js is not loading into my html.
me all confused where it should load.gave a on body load and after body load still it don't work. :(

Comment: Wrap it in the `$(function() { ... });` [DOM ready handler](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). Since the JS will only be evaluated on DOM ready, you can place it anywhere, but **after** jQuery.

Comment: ., Can you please give the whole new set of code. am all confused about this as am a newbie in js. :P

Comment: Updated the code. But it would be advisavle that you read up on the basics of jQuery: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics and https://medium.com/coding-design/how-can-you-write-better-in-jquery-69788663201e

Answer (score 1):

ok., i found the solution completely.
if anyone have any issue with this please report.

```js
function whichAnimationEvent() {
  var t;
  var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
  var animations = {
    'animation': 'animationend',
    'OAnimation': 'oAnimationEnd',
    'MozAnimation': 'animationend',
    'WebkitAnimation': 'webkitAnimationEnd'
  };

  for (t in animations) {
    if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
      return animations[t];
    }
  }
}

function oload() {
    var animationEvent = whichAnimationEvent(),
      progress = document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar')[0];

    animationEvent && progress.addEventListener(animationEvent, function() {
      window.location.replace("http://alokraj68.in");
    });
  }
  // Listen for animation
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  font: 300 1em/1.5em"Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2.25em;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.progress {
  background-color: #e5e9eb;
  height: 0.25em;
  position: relative;
  width: 24em;
}
.progress-bar {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-name: width;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4cd964, #5ac8fa, #007aff, #34aadc, #5856d6, #ff2d55);
  background-size: 24em 0.25em;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-shadow {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eaecee, transparent);
  height: 4em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transform: skew(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
/* ANIMATIONS */

@keyframes width {
  0%, 100% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.65, 0.85);
  }
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes width {
  0%, 100% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.65, 0.85);
  }
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>alokraj68.in--Loading!!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loading.css">
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="oload()">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">alokraj68.in</h1>
    <h2 class="text-center">Loading</h2>
    <div class="progress">
      <div id="pb" class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-shadow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Try this coding.
if anyone finds any issues, please tell me.